# $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \biggl|\frac{1}{(1+\sin x)\log(\sin x)}+\frac{1}{\cos^2x} \biggl| $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> > $$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \biggl|\frac{1}{(1+\sin x)\log(\sin x)}+\frac{1}{\cos^2x} \biggl| $$

**My Approach:**

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \biggl|\frac{1}{(1+\sin x)\log(\sin x)}+\frac{1}{(1-\sin x)(1+\sin x)} \biggl|$$

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{2}\biggl|\frac{1}{\log(\sin x)}+\frac{1}{(1-\sin x)} \biggl| $$

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{2}\biggl|\frac{(\sin x - 1)}{(\sin x-1)\log(1+(\sin x - 1))}+\frac{1}{(1-\sin x)} \biggl|$$

I could not processed further.

**By Applying  L'Hôpital's Rule I get answer $0$ but given answer is $\frac{1}{4}$**

Also L'Hôpital's Rule is going lengthy.

Comment: Hint: $$\log(1+\sin x-1)=\sin x-1-\frac{{(\sin x-1)}^2}{2}+....$$

Comment: Try writing $u=\sin x$ and taking the limit as $u\to1$

Comment: You can say $x = \frac {\pi}{2} + u$ and you have a limit as $u$ approaches $0.$   All of your sine functions will become cosine functions and your cosine functions will be sine functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me use $\ln$ in place of $\log$ and get from your third line
$$\frac{1}{\ln(\sin x)}+\frac{1}{(1-\sin x)} =\frac{1-\sin x+\ln(\sin x)}{(1-\sin x)\ln(\sin x)} = \\=
\frac{1-\sin x+\sin x -1+(\sin x-1)^2\frac{1}{2}-(\sin x - 1)^3\frac{1}{3}+\cdots}{-(\sin x - 1)^2}\to -\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=\sin x \to 1$ to obtain

$$\frac{1}{(1+\sin x)\log(\sin x)}+\frac{1}{\cos^2x}=\frac{1}{(1+u)\log u}+\frac{1}{1-u^2}=\frac{1-u+\log u}{(1-u^2)\log u} $$

and by $v=u-1 \to 0$

$$\frac{\log (1+v)-v}{-v(v+2)\log (1+v)}=\frac{\log (1+v)-v}{v^2}\frac{v}{-v(v+2)}\frac{v}{\log (1+v)}\to -\frac12\cdot -\frac12\cdot 1=\frac14$$